# I'm making a simple long d&d recreation and everything works ok, untill when I choose my gender as a male. And then 2 characters come out not one

Tags: python, python-3.x

Everything works fine beside the male gender print. When it's selected as a female only one name and surname of the selected race are printed on the screen. But when I select male there are two different character names. First the male one for which race I selected and then in another row a random one. I really don't know what went wrong because the male to female code is really similar and I've checked for mistakes.

```
import random

#https://www.dndbeyond.com/races

#DM introduction
print(
    f"Hi, my name is Lones and I will be your Dungeon Master today. I will walk you trough the simple edition of Dungeons and Dragons with different twists and rules which differ from the original. I hope you'll enjoy your stay."
)
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#Character Introduction
print(
    f"There are 9 races between you can chose for now. I will provide you with some info on their background and strengths so that you can understand them. This game is going to be decided by luck / by roling the dice. I will provide you with the whole list after introductions in case you forgot the races.")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#1.Dragoborn
print(f"1. Dragonborn -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"Born of dragons, as their name proclaims, the dragonborn walk proudly through a world that greets them with fearful incomprehension. Shaped by draconic gods or the dragons themselves, dragonborn originally hatched from dragon eggs as a unique race, combining the best attributes of dragons and humanoids. "
)
print(f"-Strength + 2, Charisma + 1")
print(
    f"-Damage resistance to the damage type associated with draconic ancestry")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#2.Dwarf
print(f"2. Dwarf -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"Kingdoms rich in ancient grandeur, halls carved into the roots of mountains, the echoing of picks and hammers in deep mines and blazing forges, a commitment to clan and tradition, and a burning hatred of goblins and orcs—these common threads unite all dwarves. "
)
print(f"-Constitution + 2, Wisdom + 1")
print(f"-Poison resistance")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#3.Elf
print(f"3. Elf -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"Elves are a magical people of otherworldly grace, living in the world but not entirely part of it. They live in places of ethereal beauty, in the midst of ancient forests or in silvery spires glittering with faerie light, where soft music drifts through the air and gentle fragrances waft on the breeze. "
)
print(f"-Dexterity + 2, Intelligence + 1")
print(f"-Perception skill")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#4.Gnome
print(f"4. Gnome -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"A constant hum of busy activity pervades the warrens and neighborhoods where gnomes form their close-knit communities. Louder sounds punctuate the hum: a crunch of grinding gears here, a minor explosion there, a yelp of surprise or triumph, and especially bursts of laughter.  "
)
print(f"-Intelligence + 2, Dexterity + 1")
print(f"-Stone Camouflage")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#5.Half-Elf
print(f"5. Half-Elf -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"Walking in two worlds but truly belonging to neither, half-elves combine what some say are the best qualities of their elf and human parents: human curiosity, inventiveness, and ambition tempered by the refined senses, love of nature, and artistic tastes of the elves. Some half-elves live among humans, set apart by their emotional and physical differences, watching friends and loved ones age while time barely touches them.  "
)
print(f"-Charisma + 2, two abilities scores of your choice + 1")
print(f"-You gain proficiency in two skills of your choice.")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#6.Halfing
print(f"6. Halfing -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"The comforts of home are the goals of most halflings’ lives: a place to settle in peace and quiet, far from marauding monsters and clashing armies; a blazing fire and a generous meal; fine drink and fine conversation. Though some halflings live out their days in remote agricultural communities, others form nomadic bands that travel constantly, lured by the open road and the wide horizon to discover the wonders of new lands and peoples. "
)
print(f"-Dexterity + 2, Charisma + 1")
print(f"-Naturally Stealthy, Lucky and Brave")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#7.Half-Orc
print(f"7. Half-Orc -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"Whether united under the leadership of a mighty warlock or having fought to a standstill after years of conflict, orc and human tribes sometimes form alliances, joining forces into a larger horde to the terror of civilized lands nearby. When these alliances are sealed by marriages, half-orcs are born.  "
)
print(f"-Strength + 2, Dexterity + 1")
print(f"-Intimidation skill")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#8.Human
print(f"8. Human -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"In the reckonings of most worlds, humans are the youngest of the common races, late to arrive on the world scene and short-lived in comparison to dwarves, elves, and dragons. Perhaps it is because of their shorter lives that they strive to achieve as much as they can in the years they are given.  "
)
print(
    f"-Each ability score + 1, you gain proficiency in one skill of your choice"
)
print(f"-Intimidation skill")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

#9.Tiefling
print(f"9. Tiefling -->")
print(f"   '  ")
print(f"----------------")

input()

print(
    f"To be greeted with stares and whispers, to suffer violence and insult on the street, to see mistrust and fear in every eye: this is the lot of the tiefling. And to twist the knife, tieflings know that this is because a pact struck generations ago infused the essence of Asmodeus—overlord of the Nine Hells—into their bloodline.  "
)
print(f"Charisma + 2, Intelligence + 1")
print(f"-Intimidation skill")
print(f"-Fire Resistance")
print(f"------------------------------------")

input()

print(f"1. Dragonborn -->")
print(f"2. Dwarf -->")
print(f"3. Elf -->")
print(f"4. Gnome -->")
print(f"5. Half-Elf -->")
print(f"6. Halfing -->")
print(f"7. Half-Orc -->")
print(f"8. Human -->")
print(f"9. Tiefling -->")

print(f"----------------")

Dragonborn = 1
Dwarf = 2
Elf = 3
Gnome = 4
Half_Elf = 5
Halfing = 6
Half_Orc = 7
Human = 8
Tiefling = 9


input()

dice = random.randrange(1, 9)
dice1 = random.randrange(1, 9)


if (dice == Dragonborn):
    print(f"You got Dragonborn")
elif (dice == Dwarf):
    print(f"You got Dwarf")
elif (dice == Elf):
    print(f"You got Elf")
elif (dice == Gnome):
    print(f"You got Gnome")
elif (dice == Half_Elf):
    print(f"You got Half-Elf")
elif (dice == Halfing):
    print(f"You got Halfing")
elif (dice == Half_Orc):
    print(f"You got Half-Orc")
elif (dice == Human):
    print(f"You got Human")
elif (dice == Tiefling):
    print(f"You got Tiefling")

print(f"----------------")

response = input(f"If you're happy by the choice of your dice type continue and if you aren't type reroll: ")
if(response == "continue"):
  print(f"You wish to continue the game")
elif(response == "reroll"):
  print(f"You wish to reroll the dice. This is your last roll this round.")
  if (dice1 == Dragonborn):
    print(f"You got Dragonborn")
  elif (dice1 == Dwarf):
    print(f"You got Dwarf")
  elif (dice1 == Elf):
    print(f"You got Elf")
  elif (dice1 == Gnome):
    print(f"You got Gnome")
  elif (dice1 == Half_Elf):
    print(f"You got Half-Elf")
  elif (dice1 == Halfing):
    print(f"You got Halfing")
  elif (dice1 == Half_Orc):
    print(f"You got Half-Orc")
  elif (dice1 == Human):
    print(f"You got Human")
  elif (dice1 == Tiefling):
    print(f"You got Tiefling")
else:
  print("You didn't type what I told you to")

print(f"----------------")

#Identity for Dragonborn
nameM1 = ["Arjhan", "Balasar", "Bharash", "Donaar", "Ghesh", "Heskan", "Kriv", "Medrash", "Mehen","Nadarr", "Pandjed", "Patrin","Rhogar", "Shamash", "Shedinn", "Tarhun", "Torinn"]
nameF1 = ["Akra", "Biri", "Daar", "Farideh", "Harann", "Havilar", "Jheri", "Kava", "Korinn", "Mishann", "Nala", "Perra", "Raiann", "Sora", "Surina", "Thava", "Uadjit"]
surname1 = ["Clethtinthiallor", "Daardendrian", "Delmirev", "Drachedandion", "Fenkenkabradon", "Kepeshkmolik", "Kerrhylon", "Kimbatuul", "Linxakasendalor", "Myastan", "Nemmonis","Norixius", "Ophinshtalajiir", "Prexijandilin", "Shestendeliath", "Turnuroth", "Verthisathurgiesh", "Yarjerit"]

gender = input("If you want your character to be male type M and if you want your character bo female type F: ")

Dragonborn_Mname = random.choice(nameM1) + " " + random.choice(surname1)
Dragonborn_Fname = random.choice(nameF1) + " " + random.choice(surname1)

if(dice == Dragonborn or dice1 == Dragonborn and gender == "M"):
  print(f"Your name is {Dragonborn_Mname}")
elif(dice == Dragonborn or dice1 == Dragonborn and gender == "F"):
  print(f"Your name is {Dragonborn_Fname}")


#Identity for Dwarf
nameM2 = ["Adrik", "Alberich", "Baern", "Barendd", "Brottor", "Bruenor", "Dain", "Darrak", "Delg","Eberk", "Einkil", "Fargrim", "Flint", "Gardain", "Harbek", "Kildrak", "Morgran", "Orsik", "Oskar", "Rangrim", "Rurik", "Taklinn", "Thoradin", "Thorin", "Tordek", "Traubon", "Travok", "Ulfgar", "Veit", "Vondal"]
nameF2 = ["Amber", "Artin", "Audhild", "Bardryn", "Dagnal", "Diesa", "Eldeth", "Falkrunn", "Finellen", "Gunnloda", "Gurdis", "Helja", "Hlin", "Kathra", "Kristryd", "Ilde", "Liftrasa", "Mardred", "Riswynn", "Sannl", "Torbera", "Torgga", "Vistra"]
surname2 = ["Balderk", "Battlehammer", "Brawnanvil", "Dankil", "Fireforge", "Frostbeard","Gorunn", "Holderhek", "Ironfist", "Loderr", "Lutgehr", "Rumnaheim", "Strakeln", "Torunn", "Ungart"]

Dwarf_Mname = random.choice(nameM2) + " " + random.choice(surname2)
Dwarf_Fname = random.choice(nameF2) + " " + random.choice(surname2)

if (dice == Dwarf or dice1 == Dwarf and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Dwarf_Mname}")
elif (dice == Dwarf or dice1 == Dwarf and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Dwarf_Fname}")

#Identity for Elf
nameM3 = ["Adran", "Aelar", "Aramil", "Arannis", "Aust", "Beiro", "Berrian", "Carric", "Enialis", "Erdan", "Erevan", "Galinndan", "Hadarai", "Heian", "Himo", "Immeral", "Ivellios", "Laucian", "Mindartis", "Paelias", "Peren", "Quarion", "Riardon", "Rolen", "Soveliss", "Thamior", "Tharivol", "Theren", "Varis"]
nameF3 = ["Adrie", "Althaea", "Anastrianna", "Andraste", "Antinua", "Bethrynna", "Birel", "Caelynn", "Drusilia", "Enna", "Felosial", "Ielenia", "Jelenneth", "Keyleth", "Leshanna", "Lia", "Meriele", "Mialee", "Naivara", "Quelenna", "Quillathe", "Sariel", "Shanairra", "Shava", "Silaqui", "Theirastra", "Thia", "Vadania", "Valanthe", "Xanaphia"]
surname3 = ["Amakiir", "Amastacia", "Galanodel", "Holimion", "Ilphelkiir", "Liadon", "Meliamne" , "Naïlo", "Siannodel", "Xiloscient"]

Elf_Mname = random.choice(nameM3) + " " + random.choice(surname3)
Elf_Fname = random.choice(nameF3) + " " + random.choice(surname3)

if (dice == Elf or dice1 == Elf and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Elf_Mname}")
elif (dice == Elf or dice1 == Elf and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Elf_Fname}")

#Identity for Gnome
nameM4 = ["Alston", "Alvyn", "Boddynock", "Brocc", "Burgell", "Dimble", "Eldon", "Erky", "Fonkin", "Frug", "Gerbo", "Gimble", "Glim", "Jebeddo", "Kellen", "Namfoodle", "Orryn", "Roondar", "Seebo", "Sindri", "Warryn", "Wrenn", "Zook"]
nameF4 = ["Bimpnottin", "Breena", "Caramip","Carlin", "Donella", "Duvamil", "Ella", "Ellyjobell", "Ellywick", "Lilli", "Loopmottin", "Lorilla", "Mardnab", "Nissa", "Nyx", "Oda", "Orla", "Roywyn", "Shamil", "Tana", "Waywocket", "Zanna"]
surname4 = ["Beren", "Daergel", "Folkor", "Garrick", "Nackle", "Murnig", "Ningel", "Raulnor", "Scheppen", "Timbers", "Turen"]

Gnome_Mname = random.choice(nameM4) + " " + random.choice(surname4)
Gnome_Fname = random.choice(nameF4) + " " + random.choice(surname4)

if (dice == Gnome or dice1 == Gnome and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Gnome_Mname}")
elif (dice == Gnome or dice1 == Gnome and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Gnome_Mname}")

#Identity for Half-Elf
if (dice == Half_Elf or dice1 == Half_Elf and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Half-elves use either human or elven naming conventions. You can type your own name for your character, make sure it's meant for a male, first type the name and then the last name.")
    Half_Elf_Mname = input("Your name is: ")
elif (dice == Half_Elf or dice1 == Half_Elf and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Half-elves use either human or elven naming conventions. You can type your own name for your character, make sure it's meant for a female, first type the name and then the last name.")
    Half_Elf_Fname = input("Your name is: ")

#Identity for Halfing
nameM6 = ["Alton", "Ander", "Cade", "Corrin", "Eldon", "Errich", "Finnan", "Garret", "Lindal", "Lyle", "Merric", "Milo", "Osborn", "Perrin", "Reed", "Roscoe", "Wellby"]
nameF6 = ["Andry", "Bree", "Callie", "Cora", "Euphemia", "Jillian", "Kithri", "Lavinia", "Lidda", "Merla", "Nedda", "Paela", "Portia", "Seraphina", "Shaena", "Trym", "Vani", "Verna"]
surname6 = ["Brushgather", "Goodbarrel", "Greenbottle", "High-hill", "Hilltopple", "Leagallow", "Tealeaf", "Thorngage", "Tosscobble", "Underbough"]

Halfing_Mname = random.choice(nameM6) + " " + random.choice(surname6)
Halfing_Fname = random.choice(nameF6) + " " + random.choice(surname6)

if (dice == Halfing or dice1 == Halfing and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Halfing_Mname}")
elif (dice == Halfing or dice1 == Halfing and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Halfing_Fname}")

#Identity for Half-Orc
nameM7 = ["Dench", "Feng", "Gell", "Henk", "Holg", "Imsh", "Keth", "Krusk", "Mhurren", "Ront", "Shump", "Thokk"]
nameF7 = ["Baggi", "Emen", "Engong", "Kansif", "Myev", "Neega", "Ovak", "Ownka", "Shautha", "Sutha", "Vola", "Volen", "Yevelda"]


Half_Orc_Mname = random.choice(nameM7) 
Half_Orc_Fname = random.choice(nameF7)

if (dice == Half_Orc or dice1 == Half_Orc and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Half_Orc_Mname}")
elif (dice == Half_Orc or dice1 == Half_Orc and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Half_Orc_Mname}")

#Identity for Human
if (dice == Human or dice1 == Human and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Being a human yourself I'll let you name your character, make sure it's meant for a male, first type the name and then the last name.")
    Human_Mname = input("Your name is: ")
elif (dice == Human or dice1 == Human and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Being a human yourself I'll let you name your character, make sure it's meant for a female, first type the name and then the last name.")
    Human_Fname = input("Your name is: ")

#Identity for Tiefling
nameM9 = ["Akmenos", "Amnon", "Barakas", "Damakos", "Ekemon", "Iados", "Kairon", "Leucis", "Melech", "Mordai", "Morthos", "Pelaios", "Skamos", "Therai"]
nameF9 = ["Akta", "Anakis", "Bryseis", "Criella", "Damaia", "Ea", "Kallista", "Lerissa", "Makaria", "Nemeia", "Orianna", "Phelaia", "Rieta"]
surname9 = ["Art", "Carrion", "Chant", "Creed", "Despair", "Excellence", "Fear", "Glory", "Hope", "Ideal", "Music", "Nowhere", "Open", "Poetry", "Quest", "Random", "Reverence", "Sorrow", "Temerity", "Torment", "Weary"]

Tiefling_Mname = random.choice(nameM9) + " " + random.choice(surname9)
Tiefling_Fname = random.choice(nameF9) + " " + random.choice(surname9)

if (dice == Tiefling or dice1 == Tiefling and gender == "M"):
    print(f"Your name is {Tiefling_Mname}")
elif (dice == Tiefling or dice1 == Tiefling and gender == "F"):
    print(f"Your name is {Tiefling_Fname}")


print(f"------------------------------------")
```

Comment: Expecting us to troubleshoot more than 350 lines of code for you is not realistic. Please reduce this to a [mre]

Comment: "click enter". But my mouse doesn't have an enter key!

Comment: @tripleee I know it's a lot of lines, that's why I told you where the problem is --> with the male response and that's just one line, you can search on the page by using ctrl + f in order to find it. But its fine now

Answer (score 1):

OKay, i found the issue.
You have

```
dice = random.randrange(1, 9)
dice1 = random.randrange(1, 9)
```

Both are assigned values. So when you have following `if` and `elif` statements

```
if(dice == Dragonborn or dice1 == Dragonborn and gender == "M"):
elif(dice == Dragonborn or dice1 == Dragonborn and gender == "F"):
// and for all other race
```

even if `dice == something` is false, it will still check for `dice1 == something`. 
So two times names will be printed. 
-> when `dice == something`
-> when `dice1 == something`

instead of 2 variables, just reassign the value to same variable when user choose to reroll:

```
dice = random.randrange(1, 9)
....
elif(response == "reroll"):
  print(f"You wish to reroll the dice. This is your last roll this round.")
  dice = random.randrange(1, 9)
```

and for `if` and `elif` :

```
if(dice == something and gender == "M"):
elif(dice == something and gender == "F"):
```

Also there's too many code duplication. try to reduce it.

I did few, see if you can apply it.
This is for storing data(mname, fname,surname) and using dictionary as its suits well here.

```
race = {
    1:'race1',
    2:'race2',
    3:'race3',
        }
data = {
    "Dragonbone":{
        "M":['mname1','mname2','mname3'],
        "F":['fname1','fname2','fname3'],
        "surname":['sname1','sname2','sname3']
        },
    "Half-Orc":{
        "M":['mname1','mname2','mname3'],
        "F":['fname1','fname2','fname3'],
        "surname":[] # leave them empty if they dont get these
        },
    "Human":{
        "M":[],
        "F":[],
        "surname":[]
        },
    }
```

Creating this function for generating username.

```
def generateName(race,name,surname):
    # checking if name is empty
    if not name: 
        print(f"Being a {race} yourself I'll let you name your character,first type the name and then the last name.")
        yourname = input("Your name is: ")
    # checking if surname is empty
    elif not surname:
        yourname = random.choice(name)
    else:
        yourname = random.choice(name) + " " + random.choice(surname)
    return yourname
```

for calling the function,

```
dice = random.randrange(1, 9)
sex = input("M or F");
# After confirming user for 'continue' or 'reroll'
print(generateName(race[dice],data[race[dice]][sex],data[race[dice]]["surname"]))
```

This way it'll be reusable and reducing lots of duplicate codes.

Comment: I know what you are trying to say, but the thing here is that dice and dice1 aren't the same, they might be in the same range but the numbers differ and that is why I used or on the If syntax. The dice variable is meant if the user chooses to continue and the dice1 if he chooses to reroll. If I reassign the variable the value will change because of the random function and I need them to stay the same as they were from beggining. And I can't use only one variable for dice because it changes when I choose to reroll, so I want the number before the change and after and that is why I have 2 of em.

Comment: yeah, dice and dice1 are not the same, thats why 2 names are printed.

Comment: when 'continue', `dice==something` will give you expected output and `dice1==something`will give `random` output.

Comment: vice versa, when 'reroll', `dice1==something` will give you random output and `dice1==something` will give expected output.

Comment: `it changes when I choose to reroll` yes, which is why I added `dice = random.randrange(1, 9)`  under `elif(response == "reroll"):`. If the user chooses to reroll, it'll assign another random value to `dice` which is what you want.

Comment: Yea I noticed later on, it works thanks.

Comment: @LukaAžman  you r welcome, now to try to reduce code duplication

Comment: @LukaAžman have you started reducing code duplication?

Comment: No I have not. Today I've been doing mostly html and I haven't had time to change much of the code for D&D

Comment: @LukaAžman I've added some, check if it's works well.